# Appcenter is empty and didn't get receive error when app crash

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

Using react-native with MS Appcenter. Configure everything according to the docuement.

When the app crash, Appcenter didn't receive crash report.

What happen?

What is `DO_NOT_ASK_JAVASCRIPT`?

```
<string name="appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes" moduleConfig="true" translatable="false">DO_NOT_ASK_JAVASCRIPT</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

this setting means that crashes will be sent automatically, without confirmation in js code. 
Do you have debugger attached to the app? Do you see crashes under Unsymbolicated tab on the portal?